# next steps after deploying Django and react app to Azure app service

Tags: reactjs, django, azure, azure-web-app-service, web-deployment

I am failry new to Clouad Service and I have a React and Django web app running on Azure app service.

**Thing that I have done already.**

1. Django and react app up and running fine locally.
2. 2 docker Images with 2 containers deployed into Azure App service.
3. I have one azure resource registry and 1 app service with two docker containers (frontend and backend)
4. Both react and django  are up and running in azure app service and are accessible using similar to following urls.

   `frontend.azurewebsites.net #This is just a sample name`

   `djangorestapi.azurewebsites.net #This is just a sample name`

I wanna publish this to public using domain. I am aware that I have to buy a domain and stuff. I would really appreciate if somebody can point out what are the next steps to follow.  I wanna make it available to public.

Also, with new changes I need to fix my React restapi endpoits which I made it using Django Rest Framework.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to customize your web app with a domain name other than the default `azurewebsites.net`, you can add a custom domain to your web app, also securing it with a free certificate from App Service Managed Certificates.

If you already have an existing custom DNS name, you just have to [map it with your App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain?tabs=cname). Make sure you can edit DNS records for your custom domain. If you don't have a custom domain yet, you can first [purchase an App Service domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-custom-dns-buy-domain), and then map the App Service domain to your app.

Check [this](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/07/28/zero_to_hero_pt5.html) blog post for a detailed walkthrough.

**Note:** Your webapp's App Service plan has to be on any of the non-free tiers (D1, B1, B2, B3, or any tier in the Production category) to be able to use Custom Domains.